# OSError: operation not permitted os.setegid

Tags: python

I get an "operation not permitted" traceback with trying to use os.setegid(). I've found a few answers to similar questions to this one, but the questions are more complicated than my case, and the answers presume the users did a setuid first, or suggest setting the setgid bit on the directory.

This issue is much simpler. I'm just doing a os.setegid with group id that I am a member of. In the shell I can use sg(), newgrp(), or chgrp() with the same group successfully. Why does this python command fail?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.setegid(34007)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
>>>
```

I am using RHEL7 and an older version of python (2.7.5) but the same error occurs with python 3.6.10, though in that case it's a PermissionError rather than an OSError.

Comment: `sg` and `newgrp` -- like `sudo` -- are setuid-root, so they run as superuser even when invoked by a non-privileged user. Your Python program is not. (`chgrp` changes file permissions and is thus a completely different thing).

Comment: ...that's part of why using the `sg()` notation is misleading -- it implies that `sg` is a function in shell. It's not a function; it's a whole *separate program*, so it runs in a different process than the shell that calls it, and thus can have privilege escalation take place at that boundary.

Comment: Thanks. I should have realized that. It seems unlikely that we will be able to get our admins to make python setuid (and dangerous, anyway. )

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you're running as root.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-getegid-and-os-setegid-method/

> ...method is typically available only to the superuser. Superuser
>   means a root user or an administrative user who has all the
>   permissions to run or execute any program in the operating system

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, that isn't an option for me.